# When Wordpress Default table, Echo Success. When Plugin Table, Echo Blank

Tags: mysql, wpdb

When I used this code, the result/echo display as I wanted.

```
<?php
$user_checks = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT ID, user_nicename
    FROM $wpdb->users
    "
);

foreach ( $user_checks as $user_check ) 
{
    echo $user_check->ID;
    echo $user_check->user_nicename;
}
?>
```

But when I choose table other then what wordpress provide e.g:

```
<?php
    $user_checks = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "
        SELECT id, name
        FROM $wpdb->uap_banners
        "
    );

    foreach ( $user_checks as $user_check ) 
    {
    echo $user_check->id;   
    echo $user_check->name;
    }
    ?>
```

The Result is blank... Did I miss something? (I'm new on wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$wpdb` does not contain any reference to custom tables. So the `uap_banners` property doesn't exist. You need to write in the table name the say way it was written when creating the table. So in your case that would probably be (assuming you included the database prefix):

```
$user_checks = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT id, name
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}uap_banners
    "
);
```

Comment: Ghosh! You an expert on this. Salute you Mr Jacob Peattie. Thank you so much. I will put your name as a credit on my blog